# Pass OS values to extJS app

Tags: apache, extjs, external

How can I access external system values from within an ExtJS application? One of the main reasons I need to do this is that instead of doing authentication from my ExtJS application, I am using Apache to provide this to protected directories on my server, so I want to be able to pass some of the information about the user to the application, once authenticated and the app opened. It is far easier to use LDAP authentication in this manner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass those values through:

**Apache → Backend App → Generated HTML → Frontend App (Ext JS)**

Your backend application, whatever technology it is built on, will see authentication information from Apache in environment variables. The actual variable names will depend on your setup. This is easily googlable as:

```
apache auth user environment variable <YOUR_BACKEND_TECHNOLOGY>
```

Then, the information obtained from Apache will need to be inserted in the HTML as JavaScript/JSON bit like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var AUTH_INFO = {
        "username": "John Smith"
        // other information
    };
</script>
```

Note that it needs to be inserted *before* Ext JS code.

Finally, in your Ext JS app, just access that info as a global variable:

```
AUTH_INFO.username
```

Comment: Nice! I'll play around with this and post the final result.

Comment: Got it. My backend is Flask, and I have access to all environment variables using the request object, specifically for my use case, request.remote_user. Will complete the chain later, but seems like it should be fairly straightforward. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Pleasure, happy it was helpful.